# Return from inner function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery-powered JavaScript function which iterates over a list of fields and checks to see whether they are empty; if so, blocks the submission of the form.

```
required_fields.forEach(function(field) {
    if (field.val() == '')
    {
        field.addClass('field-highlight');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        field.removeClass('field-highlight');
    }
});

// I want to return to here from the return false point
```

How can I structure this differently to do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a variable to keep track of the validation:

```
var is_valid = true;

required_fields.forEach(function(field) {
    if (field.val() == '') {
        field.addClass('field-highlight');
        is_valid = false;
        return false;
    } else  {
        field.removeClass('field-highlight');
    }
});

return is_valid;
```

Or, you can just use the `field-highlight` class as well:

```
required_fields.forEach(function(field) {
    if (field.val() == '') {
        field.addClass('field-highlight');
        return false;
    } else  {
        field.removeClass('field-highlight');
    }
});

return $('.field-highlight').length == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use a boolean in the forEach closure, which would be set to true, if the field value is empty. Check that value before submission of form

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do the following

- Update the elements with the `field-highlight` class based on whether or not they have a value
- Block the form submission if any are empty

If so then try the following

```
var anyEmpty = false;
required_fields.forEach(function() {
  if ($(this).value() == '') {
    $(this).addClass('field-highlight');
    anyEmpty = true;
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('field-highlight');
  }
});

if (anyEmpty) {
  // Block the form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the "forEach" function? If so, that could check the return value of the anon function, and if it is ever false, stop iterating.

Comment: forEach is a jQuery helper function

Comment: @Evan - Is it an undocumented part of the API?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that hastily. I was thinking of this one: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: I see it in the jquery 1.5 roadmap

Answer (score 0):

If your `required_fields` is a jQuery object, you could just do this:

```
var stop = required_fields.removeClass('field-highlight')
                          .filter("[value == '']").addClass('field-highlight')
                          .length;

return !!stop
```

Or perhaps more efficient like this?

```
var stop = required_fields.filter('.field-highlight').removeClass('field-highlight')
                          .end().filter("[value == '']").addClass('field-highlight')
                          .length;

return !!stop
```